# react native navigation custom animated transition

Tags: animation, react-native, navigation

I'm  using react native v0.49 and I'm trying to implement custom transition when navigate to other page.
what I'm trying to do is to make transition only for one scene from scene 2 to scene3. but not for all the app. 
this example I found it's for all web so I want to make just for one screen and for all the app because if I do that way it will effect for all the app and it's not what I'm looking for. any idea?

```js
    class SceneOne extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{'Scene One'}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
class SceneTwo extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{'Scene Two'}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}


let AppScenes = {
    SceneOne: {
        screen: SceneOne
    },
    SceneTwo: {
        screen: SceneTwo
    },


SceneThree: {
            screen: SceneTwo
        },
}

let MyTransition = (index, position) => {
    const inputRange = [index - 1, index, index + 1];
    const opacity = position.interpolate({
        inputRange,
        outputRange: [.8, 1, 1],
    });

    const scaleY = position.interpolate({
        inputRange,
        outputRange: ([0.8, 1, 1]),
    });

    return {
        opacity,
        transform: [
            {scaleY}
        ]
    };
};


let TransitionConfiguration = () => {
    return {
        // Define scene interpolation, eq. custom transition
        screenInterpolator: (sceneProps) => {

            const {position, scene} = sceneProps;
            const {index} = scene;

            return MyTransition(index, position);
        }
    }
};

class App extends Component {
    return (
        <View>
            <AppNavigator />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Which navigation library are you using ?

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org with this library

Comment: You can implement a transitioner and pass props to tell which transition to use https://reactnavigation.org/docs/views/transitioner

Comment: Do u have specific example how to use it? Not sure how transiator work

Comment: Please change the title of this question to `React Native - React Navigation...` There is a library called `React Native Navigation` and the title implies you're asking for help with that library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example of how we do it, you can add your own transitions to make it your own. Our goal was simply to expose the baked-in transition configurations to have more control over the animations. Our transition configuration: https://gist.github.com/jasongaare/db0c928673aec0fba7b4c8d1c456efb6

Then, in your `StackNavigator`, add that config like so:

```
StackNavigator(
  {
    LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
    HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
  },
  {
    stateName: 'MainStack',
    initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
    initialRouteParams: { transition: 'fade' },
    transitionConfig: TransitionConfig,
   }
);
```

Finally, when you navigate, just add your params when you navigate:

`this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen',  { transition: 'vertical' })`

Comment: thank you jason. where can I see what forVertical function do? I want to make transition of flip on translateY between two specific page, any idea how can I implement it?

Comment: Here's the forVertical function direct from source https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/368bc615c10a886d2aad411113c0dda046a290b6/src/views/CardStack/CardStackStyleInterpolator.js#L82-L115

I'm not certain how you might do the flip, but you can can look at all those transition configs in that file - I'd recommend messing with the translateX, Y, and Z to achieve what you are looking for

Comment: @AdirZoari I need to show transition fade in all my screens. How can I add transition for nested stack and tab navigator