# Stack.Navigator fade-transition between Stack.Screens in React-native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

How can I add a transition effect to Stacked Screes in React-native?

```js
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
        }}
    >
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Stocks" component={StocksScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Is there a default way  to achieve a fadeIn / fadeOut effect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react native navigation custom animated transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413444/react-native-navigation-custom-animated-transition)

Comment: @AliHayder Nope, because I use a different way then configuring it via JS.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve fade effect:

```js
const forFade = ({ current }) => ({
  cardStyle: {
    opacity: current.progress,
  },
});
```

If you want to apply fade effect for the entire navigator:

```js
<Stack.Navigator
   screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
      cardStyleInterpolator: forFade,
   }}>
   <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
   <Stack.Screen name="Stocks" component={StocksScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Also you can apply `cardStyleInterpolator` for single screen via setting options:

```js
<Stack.Screen 
  name="Home" 
  component={HomeScreen} 
  options={{ cardStyleInterpolator: forFade }}/>
```

You can customize `forFade` function in order to achieve other effects, or also you can use some pre-made interpolators, as:

- forHorizontalIOS
- forVerticalIOS
- forModalPresentationIOS
- forFadeFromBottomAndroid
- forRevealFromBottomAndroid

```js
import { CardStyleInterpolators } from '@react-navigation/stack';

<Stack.Screen
  name="Profile"
  component={Profile}
  options={{
    cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forFadeFromBottomAndroid,
  }}
/>;
```

More info here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#animations

Answer (score 5):

For React Navigation 6.xx you can use the animation option:

```js
<Stack.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
        options={{ animation: 'fade' }}
/>
```

Supported values:

- "default": use the platform default animation
- "fade": fade screen in or out
- "flip": flip the screen, requires presentation: "modal" (iOS only)
- "simple_push": use the platform default animation, but without shadow and native header transition (iOS only)
- "slide_from_bottom": slide in the new screen from bottom
- "slide_from_right": slide in the new screen from right (Android only, uses default animation on iOS)
- "slide_from_left": slide in the new screen from left (Android only, uses default animation on iOS)
- "none": don't animate the screen